# Using reflection to get a specific attribute from a extended instance

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to make a generic method to get a List from the parameter object.

The problem is because I have a declared object with a instance of the other class that extends the declared class. 
I don't want to use the `instanceof` solution because the number of classes that extends LimitedValue can be big.

I thought to use reflection for a solution, but I don't know how to use that with an instance of object, in this part of the code:

```
    Class cls = Class.forName(limitedValue.getClass().getName());
    Object obj = cls.newInstance();
    //This is wrong, I don't want a new instance.

    Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(int x= 0; x < methods.length; x++) {
        Method method = methods[x];
        if ("java.util.List".equals(method.getReturnType().getName())) {
            //How to get the value of this method from limitedValue instance ?
        }
    }
```

This is my full code:

```
public class CalculatorLimitedValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StoreItem storeItem = new StoreItem(1L, "Name of StoreItem", 50L);
        List listOfStoreItems = new ArrayList();
        listOfStoreItems.add(storeItem);
        LimitedValue limitedValue0 = new Store(listOfStoreItems);

        List firstList = calculator(limitedValue0);
        //do something with the list

        SupermarketItem supermarketItem = new SupermarketItem(1L, "Name of SupermarketItem", 21L);
        List listOfSupermarketItems = new ArrayList();
        listOfSupermarketItems.add(supermarketItem);
        LimitedValue limitedValue1 = new Supermarket(listOfSupermarketItems);

        List secondList = calculator(limitedValue1);
        //do something with the list
    }

    /** This is the method that I'd like to make generic to return a List */
    private static List calculator(LimitedValue limitedValue) throws Exception{

        Class cls = Class.forName(limitedValue.getClass().getName());
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        //This is wrong, I don't want a new instance.

        Method[] methods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(int x= 0; x < methods.length; x++) {
            Method method = methods[x];
            if ("java.util.List".equals(method.getReturnType().getName())) {
                //How to get the value of this method from limitedValue instance ?
            }
        }

        /* I don't want to use this one way, because my classes that extends LimitedValue 
        can be big. I would like to made a generic way to get de list of classes. */
        if (limitedValue instanceof Store) {
            System.out.println("This is a store");
            return ((Store) limitedValue).getStoreItems();
        } else if (limitedValue instanceof Supermarket) {
            System.out.println("This is a supermarket");
            return ((Supermarket) limitedValue).getSupermarketItems();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If it help, these are my other classes:

LimitedValue.class

```
public class LimitedValue { }
```

StoreItem.class

```
public class StoreItem {
    private Long id;
    private String nameOfStoreItem;
    private Long valueOfStoreItem;

    public StoreItem(Long id, String nameOfStoreItem, Long valueOfStoreItem){ 
        this.id = id;
        this.nameOfStoreItem = nameOfStoreItem;
        this.valueOfStoreItem = valueOfStoreItem;
    }
//getters and setters...
}
```

SupermarketItem.class

```
public class SupermarketItem {
    private Long id;
    private String nameOfSupermarketItem;
    private Long valueOfSupermarketItem;

    public SupermarketItem() {
    }

    public SupermarketItem(Long id, String nameOfSupermarketItem, Long valueOfSupermarketItem) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nameOfSupermarketItem = nameOfSupermarketItem;
        this.valueOfSupermarketItem = valueOfSupermarketItem;
    }
//getters and setters...
}
```

Store.class

```
public class Store extends LimitedValue {
    private List<StoreItem> storeItems;

    public Store(List<StoreItem> storeItems) {
        this.storeItems = storeItems;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Supermarket.class

```
public class Supermarket extends LimitedValue {
    private List<SupermarketItem> supermarketItems;

    public Supermarket(List<SupermarketItem> supermarketItems) {
        this.supermarketItems = supermarketItems;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use reflection. You should use polymorphism. Learn about abstract methods and interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use reflection here to try to achieve what you want, but it would be better to reconsider your overall design and try to use a better object oriented design that solves the problem at hand.

In particular, lets say we consider adding a method called getItems to the `LimitedValue` class that returns a List of items, which may be `SupermarketItem`s or may be `StoreItem`s. If it is structured correctly, you won't need to know the actual type because the code will be abstracted over it polymorphically.

```
public abstract class LimitedValue {    
  List<? extends Item> getItems();
}
```

We've now defined a new method on `LimitedValue`, but we also have to consider that we've introduced this new Item thing. I note that the `SupermarketItem` and `StoreItem` all share similiar attributes, `name`, `id` and `value`, so it seems that it might be possible to use a single class to represent them all.

```
public abstract class Item {
  final Long id;
  final String name;
  final Long value;

  public Item(final Long id, final Long name, final Long value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // other getters and setters
}

public class SupermarketItem extends Item {
  public SupermarketItem(final Long id, final Long name, final Long value) {
    super(id, name, value);
  }
}

public class StoreItem extends Item {
  public StoreItem(final Long id, final Long name, final Long value) {
    super(id, name, value);
  }
}
```

Now we've completely abstracted away the need for any reflection when accessing these objects - you can simply call item.getValue() as you will know that every item in the list is of type Item.

Of course, you'll also need to refactor the Store and SuperMarket classes, for example:

```
public class Supermarket extends LimitedValue {
    private List<SupermarketItem> supermarketItems;

    public Supermarket(List<SupermarketItem> supermarketItems) {
        this.supermarketItems = supermarketItems;
    }

    public List<? extends Item> getItems() {
      return supermarketItems;
    }
}
```

and because you are only returning a `List<Item>` you always know what is in it, and you can change your main code to work with this.

This is a much cleaner long term solution.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `List` value, use [`Method#invoke`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html):

```
List list = method.invoke(limitedValue);
```

You don't need `Object obj = cls.newInstance();` - you're not using it at all in the method.

In any case, you're making it very difficult for yourself. You could also define an interface

```
public interface HasList<E> {
    List<E> getList();
}
```

and have all classes implement this.